# Remove Seaborn barplot legend title

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I use seaborn to plot a grouped bar plot as in https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/factorplot_bars.html

Giving me:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/factorplot_bars.png

there is a title (sex) on the legend which I would like to remove.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: You need to add the code you are using.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may be a hacky solution but it works: if you tell Seaborn to leave it off at the time of plotting and then add it back it doesn't have the legend title:

```
g = sns.factorplot(x='Age Group',y='ED',hue='Became Member',col='Coverage Type',
                   col_wrap=3,data=gdf,kind='bar',ci=None,legend=False,palette='muted')
#                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
plt.suptitle('ED Visit Rate per 1,000 Members per Year',size=16)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=.925)
plt.show()
```

Example result:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

You can remove the legend title with:

`plt.gca().legend().set_title('')`

Comment: How about in the OOP interface?

Comment: This should be the answer. It works and minimal assumptions and code.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 12):

A less hacky way is to use the object oriented interface of matplotlib. By gaining control of the axes, it will make it a lot easier to customize the plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Load the example Titanic dataset
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Draw a nested barplot to show survival for class and sex
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = sns.factorplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex", data=titanic,
                   size=6, kind="bar", palette="muted", ax=ax)
sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
ax.set_ylabel("survival probability")
l = ax.legend()
l.set_title('Whatever you want')
fig.show()
```

Results in
[image: resulting_plot]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for seaborn.lineplot (v0.9.0).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the legend to be shown outside of the plot axis, as is default for `factorplot`, you can use `FacetGrid.add_legend` (`factorplot` returns a `FacetGrid` instance). Other methods allow you to adjust the labels of every axis in the `FacetGrid` at once

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Load the example Titanic dataset
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Draw a nested barplot to show survival for class and sex
g = sns.factorplot(x="class", y="survived", hue="sex", data=titanic,
                   size=6, kind="bar", palette="muted", legend=False)
(g.despine(left=True)
  .set_ylabels('survival probability')
  .add_legend(title='Whatever you want')
)
```