# Remove seaborn lineplot legend title

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I would like to remove the title from my seaborn lineplot legend. I tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335602/2970186) to no avail:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", hue="event", data=fmri, ax=ax)
ax.legend().set_title('')
```

[image: Seaborn lineplot still with 'event' title]

I get the same if I try to set the title to `None`. Interestingly, setting the title to something else seems to prepend to the existing title:

```
ax.legend().set_title('Something else')
```

[image: Seaborn lineplot still with prepend title]

It almost looks like seaborn is treating the title as a hidden legend entry. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

***Important***: This answer is about the case when a `hue` is used that appears as a legend title. In all other cases, the question itself already contains the usual way to get rid of a title.

Indeed, seaborn is misusing a legend label as a (subgroup-)title. Hence the idea can be to either remove this label, or replace it with custom text.

**Replacing with custom text:**

```
legend = ax.legend()
legend.texts[0].set_text("Whatever else")
```

[image]

**Removing the label:**

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:])
```

[image]

After having removed the label you may of course still set another (real) title:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], title="Whatever else")
```

[image]

Comment: In all listed cases, the indexing is no longer needed.

`legend.texts[0].set_text("Whatever else")` -> `legend.texts.set_text("Whatever else")`

`ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:], ...` -> `ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, ...`

Comment: @AtifRaza That is incorrect. The first suggestion would lead to an error. The second suggestion would not remove the title.

Comment: I needed to change the legend title as well, but your suggestions were removing the legend title as well as the first legend entry. Just checked `ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, title="Split")` again after your comment, and for Seaborn 0.9.0, I am sure indexing from `[1:]` is not correct. Maybe you can check on your side if we have a version mismatch.

Comment: The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925686/2827162) by @badluck is also addressing the same thing.

Comment: @AtifRaza This answer is tested with seaborn 0.8, 0.9 and 0.10. It works correctly with each of those.

Comment: It even says `lineplot` in the question title! (The solution for other plots is already within the question.)

Answer (score 47):

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.lineplot(x="myXs", y="myYs", hue="myHue", data=mydf)
g.legend_.set_title(None)
```

Comment: Instead of directly accessing the legend instance via `legend_`, you could also use the appropriate getter functions: `g.get_legend().set_title(None)` or `g.legend().set_title(None)`

Comment: One may usually prefer `get_legend()` as it " gives you a reference to the existing legend object" while `legend()` "removes the existing legend and creates a new one". From [this Github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2669#issuecomment-926611055).

Answer (score 9):

Extending ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer:

I had the same problem, but the 'Removing the label' example removed the title and first item from the actual legend.

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles[1:], labels=labels[1:])
```

So, this removes just the legend title:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels)
```

Comment: You don't need the slice index (`[0:]`) as it has no effect. I think your solution simply recreates the legend _without specifying the title_. That assumes you had a legend title in the first place, which `seaborn` doesn't use. Did you need this solution to fix a `seaborn` plot specifically?