# Modify seaborn line relplot legend title

Tags: python, seaborn

First off, I am a newbie with both Python and seaborn, but after spending some time with this matter I believe my question has not been addressed elsewhere. If so, I sincerely apologize.

I want to use the seaborn `relplot()` function with `kind='line'` to plot data from a dataframe as several lines of different colors. The data corresponding to the lines are separated categorically by values in a column (`cat`, say) and I use `hue` (in this case, `hue='cat'`). Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 5, 6],
                   'y': [2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 10, 9, 7],
                   'cat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
g = sns.relplot(x='x', y='y', hue='cat', kind='line', data=df);
```

It produces the following graph:

[image: Example plot]

How do I modify the legend title without changing the name of the column `cat`? I believe my problem is that the legend title is actually implemented as a legend item, so what I want to do is remove that item and then add a proper legend title (which I can do using `g._legend.set_title('New title')`), but I do not know how to accomplish this.

This question differs from [Remove seaborn lineplot legend title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579215/10595482) in that `relplot()` with `kind='line'` produces a `FacetGrid` figure and attaches the legend to that one. This means I cannot access the legend content as `g.ax.legend().texts` but must use `g._legend`, in which case I am lost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One option would be to set the first legend entry to an empty string using `g._legend.texts[0].set_text("")`, then use `g._legend.set_title('New title')`

```
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 1, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 5, 6],
                   'y': [2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 10, 9, 7],
                   'cat': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]})
g = sns.relplot(x='x', y='y', hue='cat', kind='line', data=df)

g._legend.texts[0].set_text("")
g._legend.set_title("New title")
g._legend._legend_box.sep = -5  # move title down slightly

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also change the horizontal alignment using:

```
g._legend._legend_box.align = "right"  # or left, or center
```

Another option would be to draw the legend yourself:

```
g = sns.relplot(x='x', y='y', hue='cat', kind='line', data=df, legend=False)
ax =g.axes[0][0]

for i, line in enumerate(ax.lines):
    line.set_label(i)

leg = ax.legend()
leg.set_title("New title")
```

An alternative to setting the first legend entry to an empty string is shown below (suggested by ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments):

```
c = g._legend.get_children()[0].get_children()[1].get_children()[0]
c._children = c._children[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I would also like to know if it's possible to remove the first legend item, but if not I'll use this!

Comment: @RobertNyqvist Not entirely sure you can remove it using just seaborn. I think another option would be to create the legend yourself. I've updated my answer with that option.

Comment: Your new option is also useful, thanks! But outside the scope of this toy example, I want a row of such plots using `FacetGrid`, in which case the `legend_out` type legend is nice to have because it naturally applies to all plots.

Comment: @RobertNyqvist Then I would stick to the first way in my answer for now, and wait to see if anybody else knows of a better way

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but I think I don't understand in how far this answer does not already solve the issue. I guess it should either be accepted, or the question should be updated with a clearer explanation of the issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think OP wanted the first legend item to actually be removed rather than set to an empty string, but I don't think its possible?

Comment: Well, there is no remove method, but you can empty the packer, like `g._legend.get_children()[0].get_children()[1].get_children()[0].get_children()[0]._children = []`.

Comment: Or maybe better `c = g._legend.get_children()[0].get_children()[1].get_children()[0];
c._children = c._children[1:]`

Comment: @DavidG You're correct, that is indeed what I wanted. The solution by ImportanceOfBeingErnest is just what I was looking for. I will now accept your modified answer. Thanks for your contributions!

Answer (score 2):

For me, `g._legend.texts[0].set_text("")` removed the label of the *first* element in the legend, not the title. Maybe seaborn 0.11.1 defines `g._legend.texts[0]` differently.

Therefore I simply used

```
g._legend.set_title("")
```