# Issues with seaborn distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am facing a simple problem. Yet, I cannot solve it. I am trying to plot a distribution of three categories. The plotting itself is not a problem. However, changing the title of the legend does not work. What am I missing?

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_path, "test.csv"))

distplot = sb.displot(df, x="depth", hue="label", kind="kde")
distplot.fig.legend(title='Node type')

plt.show(block=True)
```

**Error**

`No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argume`nt.

**Example data**

```
label,depth
A,1
A,2
A,3
B,1
B,1
B,4
B,4
B,4
C,1
C,2
C,6
C,6
C,6
```

**Resulting plot**

[image]

Comment: [Remove seaborn lineplot legend title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51579215/7758804)

Comment: The current version of seaborn is 0.11.2. `distplot` is deprecated. Use `sns.histplot` or `sns.displot`

Comment: In this case, the recommended way to change the legend title is to (temporarily) change the name of the column used for the hue.